# Certain That and Certain To

Tags: grammaticality

Are these sentences grammatically correct? (I feel as though "it" should refer to something in the first one.)

1. It is certain that the weather will change.
2. The weather is certain to change.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe both are correct. The it in the first sentence is a placeholder for the statement avout the weather.

Comment: What is associated with this downvote? Constructive criticsm is fine, but just a negative vote is not helpful? I've heard both sentences used before, and the only object in the first sentence is "the weather"... one of the uses of "it" is "used to refer to a thing previously mentioned or easily identified."

Comment: Probably because of the avoidable, incorrect reference to *it*. The *it* here is the *existential it*, not a pronoun "referring back" to a 'thing'. I'm saving my own down vote for later, though. Have fun!

Comment: @Kris Please see: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/it. The "existential usage", which is definition number 2, does not apply here. Certain is an adjective, while the existential is used for things like the example given in the dictionary "It is raining" (note, this is a complete sentence). "It is certain" cannot stand alone, because the reader will ask..."What is certain?". The answer? The weather. In existential "it" such a question does not make sense...there is no "what" to the "it" in "it is raining".

Comment: @Kris (con't) Here's a simpler example..."It is red." This sentence simply says something is red, not the existential state of "redness" being present in the world...at least that's how most people would read it. The antecedent could be from a preceding question like "What color is that car?" But in the poster's example, we have an obvious choice for what "It" refers to.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981: No. This is the existential _it_, and doesn't refer to the weather. It is closer to MW's definition 3, not 2.

Comment: @ColinFine I see your point about Def 3 vs 2. Both defintions are under the pronoun definition of it. However, Def 3 says its an "anticipatory" subject or object, to shift emphasis off the object. So, in this case, the sentence is focusing us on the certainty...the certainty of what? The weather. Now, I am not an english major but I can't see how it cannot refer to the weather. If I asked the question "What is certain?" the answer would be "the weather"...I guess I don't get why it is devoid of a reference in this case.

Comment: No, it's not the weather. It's the statement "the weather will change". Being certain is not one of the properties of weather. (To make this clearer, substitute "It's probable" for "it's certain". The only things that are capable of being probable are statements or propositions, not weather.

Comment: Ok I see where I was off... This is an example of extraposition which is used to push a clause back in a sentence....the it then refers to the whole statement. Thanks for the clarification I will edit my post

Comment: @ColinFine Regarding what can be certain...can't events be certain as well? For example, "the outcome of the election is certain" vs. "the role of a die is uncertain". Neither of these are propositions, but events. Or am I construing statement/proposition too narrowly?

Comment: No. "The outcome" is an abstract. We do sometimes talk about events being certain, but this is metonymy for something about the outcome or occurrence of the event: _it is certain that the event will occur_ or _it is certain that the outcome of rolling the die will be favorable_.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical. *It* in the first sentence is sometimes called a ‘dummy’ *it*, because it doesn’t have an antecedent. It’s just there so that *is* can have a subject.

There isn’t much difference in meaning between the two, but they are rather artificial sentences, and, at least in conversation, a native speaker probably wouldn’t say either. More likely would be ‘Looks like the weather’s gonna change’ or ‘Don’t think this weather’s gonna last long.’